# Convert 32 bit signed int to 24 bit signed for audio data

Tags: c, audio, types

I'm trying to convert my audio data which is 32 bit signed int, into 24 bit signed.
The goal is to write a Wave file. I already managed to write correct Wave files with 8, 16 and 32 bit depths, but for some reason I struggle with 24 bit. The sound output sounds like 8 bits (lots of noise), which seems to mean only the MSB is correctly interpreted, the second and third bytes of the 24-bit value seems not working.

The code:

```
int buffer_32[1024];
unsigned char buffer_24[1024*3];

for (unsigned i = 0; i < 1024; i++)
{
    buffer_24[i*3] = (unsigned char)((buffer_32[i] & 0xff0000) >> 16);
    buffer_24[i*3+1] = (unsigned char)((buffer_32[i] & 0xff00) >> 8);
    buffer_24[i*3+2] = (unsigned char)(buffer_32[i] & 0xff);
}
```

Basically, I manipulate bytes to create a 24-bit stream ('24bit packed').

I don't know whats wrong in my conversion algorithm: can you help me?

EDIT : I forgot to say, my int values are already correctly scaled into -8388608,8388607 (24-bit signed integer) range before going into this conversion loop.

Comment: Your'e using the low-order 24 bits of the 32. You need to use the high order bits.

Comment: Have you done printing to check: `printf("0x%.6X . = %.2X %.2X %.2X\n", buffer_32[i] & 0xFFFFFF, buffer_24[i*3+0], buffer_24[i*3+1], buffer_24[i*3+2]);` as the last statement of the loop?  Do the printed values agree with each other?

Comment: Are you sure that your output byte order matches the expected byte order of whatever player you are using?  I am interested in seeing your 16-bit version of this code to see if they match.

Answer (score 3):

The reason it sounds like noise is that you're stripping the MSB from the data.

Try this instead:

```
buffer_24[i*3] = (unsigned char)((buffer_32[i] & 0xff000000) >> 24);
buffer_24[i*3+1] = (unsigned char)((buffer_32[i] & 0xff0000) >> 16);
buffer_24[i*3+2] = (unsigned char)((buffer_32[i] & 0xff00) >> 8);
```

Comment: I forgot to add that my int array contain values that are already scaled to fit in 24-bit range, so MSB is empty

Comment: Here is a hacky solution that could be used to test if the error is not in this part of the code.  Multiply the buffer_32[i] by 0x100 and then use the code given in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is over 30 years since I did this kind of stuff, so bear with me:

1. If your audio is multiplexed stereo then I doubt what you are doing works.
2. If the signed bit is for left and right then then you should work (AND) the sign out of it and work with the result and then re-attach (OR) the sign back.
3. If you are just trying to remove the top byte then you should AND out the top bytes with 0x00ffffffff (four bytes).

If it is a pure analogue sample, I would reduce the resolution (software resample), depending on what type of quality I want, reduce the volume, etc.

Trust this helps.